# Keep Multiple Double Quotes when updating a XML webconfig file

Tags: xml, powershell, double-quotes

I need to update the `network host` portion of an XML file.  You will see from the sample below that four parts are double quoted.  I am finding it difficult in my PowerShell script to update with double quotes.  I have read through a number of posts on the WWW and StackOverflow for a solution.  I include the line from my current code and the output in the xml.  Any help in this area would be welcomed.

Desired outcome in XML after running PowerShell.

```xml
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
<smtp>        
<network host="mailtrap.io" port="1234" userName="3987455k61f63dd421" password="d6jjjcfc2bf76889" />
</smtp>
```

PowerShell code

```psh
$root.SelectSingleNode("//system.net/mailSettings/smtp/network").host= "`"mailtrap.io`" port=`"1234`" userName=`"3987455k61f63dd421`" password=`" d6jjjcfc2bf76889`""
```

Actual Output in XML after code runs (note the `&quot;` instead of `"`):

```xml
<network host="&quot;mailtrap.io&quot; port=&quot;25252&quot; userName=&quot; 3987455k61f63dd421&quot; password=&quot;d6jjjcfc2bf76889&quot;" />
```

Comment: Your question is ambiguous, put your powershell code and we try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding the structure of your XML. You don't have a `network host` node there, but a `network` node with 4 attributes:

- `host`
- `port`
- `userName`
- `password`

You need to assign values to each attribute separately:

```psh
$node = $root.SelectSingleNode('//system.net/mailSettings/smtp/network')
$node.host     = 'mailtrap.io'
$node.port     = '1234'
$node.userName = '3987455k61f63dd421'
$node.password = 'd6jjjcfc2bf76889'
```

If the attributes aren't already present in the node you can create them like this:

```psh
$attr = $root.CreateAttribute('host')
$attr.Value = 'mailtrap.io'
$node.Attributes.Append($attr)
```

Comment: Hi Turican.  Sorry for late reply.  Not sure what was ambiguous in my post but thanks for the offer of help. Ansgar. I will give your suggestion a try in the morning.  Thanks for the code.

Comment: @user2987451 Your question wasn't actually ambiguous, but it appeared that way due to improper formatting (which hid part of your code).